# MEAN Stack - *refresh* on SPA webapp

Tags: node.js, angular, express, refresh, mean-stack

I'm using hash location strategy on my angular4 client side,
in development mode the refresh is working,
but when compiling to production mode (`ng build -prod`) the refresh breaks the page - the developer console show `GET <url> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `ERROR of ProgressEvent`.

on the server side (node + express) in the app.js file we have this code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    return res.render("index");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code where you have all your routes defined. Make sure that is last/below all your other routes.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: webRoot });
});
```

Where `webRoot` is the path to your Angular `dist` directory defined on your server. On your server you may define it something like `var webRoot = _dirname + '/../../client/dist';`

For more clarification check out the Official Express docs for [res.sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Comment: the `'index.html'` should point to the index.html of the angular app right?
and what `{ root: webRoot }` does?

Comment: Correct `index.html` is from your Angular app. The `{ root: webRoot }` options makes it so you DO NOT have to use an absolute path. Check out the docs for more info https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: See updated answer - I apologize I should have been more clear on what the option and variable are.

Comment: we already tried
`app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'PATH/TO/FILE/index.html'));
});`

is it the same or not, from what you wrote?

Comment: No, that is completely different from what I suggested you try. Be sure that when you add the `app.all(..)` code it is below ALL of your `app.get()`, `app.post()`, etc... route definitions.

Comment: we do not use client routes in the server, so we do not have app.get nor app.post in our app.js. Our client does not sits inside the server directory, it is in different directory. We use hashLocatoinStrategy in the client side. We tried your suggestion and it didn't work. Is there something else we can try ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to render Angular app.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```